# Flask models.py overriding attributes / columns

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a flask application where I am attempting to utilize the Inheritance capabilities of Flask.

Given a model of

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False, nullable = False)
    second_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False, nullable = False)
    third_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False, nullable = False)
    forth_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = False, nullable = False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(128), unique = False, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(25), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable = False)
    organisation_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organisation.id'), nullable = True)
    address_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('address.id'), nullable = False)
```

If I then wish to override the column, organisation_ID

```
class Staff_member(Person):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    university_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('university.id'), nullable = False)
```

Where I hope to override organisation_ID with university_ID can this be done or do I have to go about this a different way? I'm hoping to use the person class as a base class for different individuals in an organization, where the organisation_ID will be overridden.

Please note the organization class will also be another 'base' class storing generic information for organizations and so forth.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at SQLAlchemy's table inheritance:https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks very much! This is what I was after.